# A term to describe something that has both an inbound and outbound connection

Tags: meaning

(Pardon the jargon.) Suppose we have a directed graph of nodes. If one node points to another node then we might say the node has an outbound connection and the other node has an inbound connection. What term, if any, might one use to describe a node that has both an inbound and an outbound connection.

Comment: This question is more suited to [Mathematics.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do you mean "unbound" or "outbound" (in your title)?

Comment: (But seems to me you're talking about a "non-leaf node".

Comment: Fixed typo in title.

Comment: I support Michael's answer, but if you want something less rigorous, perhaps *dual* or *bi-* something, such as *bi-node*.

Comment: How about terminal, as in train terminal? I can see how this could be confusing in graph theory, but it does capture the idea of inbound and outbound connections.

Answer (score 2):

In a directed graph, a node (vertex) is either *internal* or *external*. An external node (leaf/edge) can be either *source* or *sink*.

> If a vertex is neither a *source* nor a *sink*, it is called an *internal*.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Indegree_and_outdegree